# How to avoid lists when analyzing order for palindromes?

Tags: python, palindrome

Just want to apologize in advance for the general coding and logic gore you might encounter while reading this. I recently discovered Project Euler and thought it was fun. I've made it a point to not only find the answer, but make a generic function that could find the answer for any similar case given the appropriate input. For instance, problem number 4, involving palindromes, which can be seen here: https://projecteuler.net/problem=4

Essentially what I did was found a way to multiply every possible combination of numbers given a number of digits, n, then found products that were palindromes. However, anything above 3 digits just takes way too long to process. I believe this is because I used the list() function to take advantage of indexing to determine whether the product was a palindrome. Is there another way to do something of this nature? I feel like this is shoving a square through a circular hole.

Here's the function in question.

```
def palindrome(n):
    number = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        number = number + 9 * pow(10, i)
    a = pow(10, n - 1) - 1
    b = pow(10, n - 1)
    while a * b < number * number:
        a = a + 1
        b = a
        while b <= number:
            c = a * b
            b = b + 1
            digits = list(str(int(c)))
            lastdigits = digits[::-1]
            numdigits = len(digits)
            middle = int((numdigits - (numdigits % 2)) / 2) - 1
            if numdigits > 1 and digits[:middle + 1] == lastdigits[:middle + 1] and digits[0] == digits[-1] == '9' and numdigits == 2 * n:
                print(c)
```

Comment: Your issue here is definitely _not_ related to the use of lists.  In fact, the simple solution to palindrome checking in python relies heavily on slice notation.  Your issue is in your while loops that require exponentially larger numbers of iterations based on the input value.  You should ask yourself, "are these really necessary?" (hint: they're not).

Comment: Yeah after seeing the first response I realized it's entirely how I approached a solution.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. By accepting an answer this tells others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.*"

3-digit numbers would be anything from 100 - 999. One thing about the largest product is guaranteed: The two operands must be as large as possible.

Thus, it would make sense to step through a loop starting from the largest number (999) to the smallest (100). We can append palindromes to a list and then later return the largest one.

When you calculate a product, convert it to a string using `str(...)`. Now, checking for palindromes is easy thanks to python's string splicing. A string is a palindrome if `string == string[::-1]`, where `string[::-1]` does nothing but return a reversed copy of the original.

Implementing these strategies, we have:

```
def getBiggestPalindrome():
    max_palindrome = -1
    for i in range(999, 99, -1):
        for j in range(999, i - 1, -1):
            prod = i * j
            str_prod = str(prod)
            if str_prod == str_prod[::-1] and prod > max_palindrome: 
                print(prod)
                max_palindrome = prod

    return max_palindrome
```

getBiggestPalindrome()

And, this returns

```
>>> getBiggestPalindrome()
906609
```

Note that you can use the `range` function to generate values from `start`, to `end`, with `step`. The iteration stops just before `end`, meaning the last value would be 100.

Comment: Wow dude. Shows how much I have to learn. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @quesadyllan My apologies. My previous answer was incorrect. Please have a look now. The intuition remains the same. But it is possible that a greater product exists than the one currently found, because the inner and outer loops do not run at the same speed. You may have found 999 * 100 to be a palindrome, but 998 * 997 may yield an even larger one. Looks like we do need to step through both the loops completely.

Comment: Does the inner loop really need to start at `999` or could it start at `i`?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy You, sir, are a genius. Yes, the extent of iteration for the inner loop should be `i`. I always knew there was a way to speed it up. Just couldn't think how.